# can't upgrade from webpack 3 to 3.12.0

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install

I'm trying to use a node package which requires a higher version of webpack than I have installed.

My packages.json file is [here](https://pastebin.com/hN5uEAkH).

When I try to install:

```
npm install webpack@3.12.0
```

I get the following error:

```
$ npm install webpack@3.12.0
app@1.0.0 /home/ubuntu/workspace
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.12.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.2     (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for     fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:     {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for     fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:     {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker@4.17.47 requires a peer of     bootstrap@^3.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 requires a peer of     webpack@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: Try this:

    `rm -rf node_modules/`

    `npm cache clean`

   `npm install`

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it was resolved by following the instructions stated by Vu Huu Cuong:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean
npm install
```